# Getting an exception while trying to run the Selenium Code with Chrome Driver inside tomcat

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I Have a rest endpoint in which i need to run some selenium automation (this is not for testing, but actual business process). When i try to start the driver i see the below error. Any help on this is apporaciated

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException : Could not start a new Session.

Response code : 500. Message : unknown error : cannot create temp directory for unpacking extensions

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)